# Passing form values to another GTM tag after payment page

Tags: wordpress, paypal, google-tag-manager, mollie

I'm trying to implement a conversion tracking on a site where you can donate a amount to goodwill.

The situation: 
User inputs his/hers information into a WP form with the amount he/she wants to donate. So far its that's all in place i have a tag that fires when the forum is submitted and contains the value i need after the user has finished the payment. How do I pass the value to the tag that fires when the user returns to the thank you page if it's possible at all. Are there any other methods to achieve this?

The plugins:
Mollie,
Paypal

Comment: "i have a tag that fires when the forum is submitted" - on this event you should save the value(cookie, local storage etc.). My first tip would be to save the value in the cookie. Then you can retrieve cookie value in GTM via "User-Defined Variables" - "1st Party Cookie"